# spring transaction - rollback only on true in private method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions

When I try to write, I get an exception thrown by org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException that the rollback only parameter is selected. I know what the error is related to but I do not know how I can get around it.
The error occurs because the execute () method throws an exception
Below is my pseudocode:

```
public class MyService 
{

    MyJpaRepository myJpaRepository;
    EntityManager entityManager;

        @Transactional
        @Override 
        public void doSomething(){

               MyObject myObject  = myJpaRepository.findOne(1L);               
               Try<Integer>result = updateChild(myObject.getchild());
               myObject .addResult(result .get());

                myJpaRepository.save(myObject );

        }

       Try<Integer>updateChildren(MyObjectChilden child) {
            String query = child.prepareQuery("xxx");
            Try<Integer> result = Try.of(() -> execute(query));

            if(result.isFailure()){
                  String query = child.prepareQuery("YYY"); // if I throw the error unique constraint validation change to "YYY"
                  result = Try.of(() -> execute(query ));
             }
             return result
     }

    private Integer execute(String query) {
            final Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query); // Can throw a unique constraint validation error
            return (Integer) nativeQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Generally the idea is that I've extracted execute () in order to be able to use it many times, but with another query, unfortunately this method throws an exception, which means that the rollback only parameter is selected and it is not possible to write to the database

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. You just designed your code wrong when you thought it would be clever to have a `Try(() -> execute())` construct that ignores exceptions.

Comment: So I should divide this code for several transaction part?

Comment: Probably not. That doesn't look like proper design in the first place. I don't really see any saved space with your `Try`-construct either. All it does is break your code in a non-standard way. If `doSomething()` is supposed to be transactional, then it probably needs to rollback if it can't do all necessary things.

Comment: My intention of Try-construct was to catch the exception when method thow the unique exception and then run the method again but with another parameter 'set'. Additionally, I do not want to do it in one method because I try writting clean code (I'm a beginner programmer) what should I do to make the code clean and correct ?

Comment: above is only part of the code to show my intentions and problem, I did not put all the code

Comment: Instead of putting up code which doesn't explain why you're doing what you're doing, how about using plain English to tell us what problem your code is supposed to solve?

Comment: In my public method (doSomething()) I want to do:  Get a parent from the database (parent has information about query operation for his children: update or delete). Depending on the type of query (update or delete) I must prepare dynamic query and execute, if I get unique exception during update, I should execute update query with another param. Method "updateChildren()" additionally, it measures the query execution time and on this basis creates a custom result object

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is according to specification, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html):

> All instances of PersistenceException except for instances of NoResultException, NonUniqueResultException, LockTimeoutException, and QueryTimeoutException will cause the current transaction, if one is active and the persistence context has been joined to it, to be marked for rollback.

So to solve this it'd seem you should either first query the database to see if the row to be inserted is already there or break up the code in several transactions.

Comment: Thanks @tom ! I do not know if the table has a unique restriction, so I should break up the code in several transactions.

Comment: Ok, then i'd go with starting a new transaction before the execute, so the rollback of that transaction doesn't affect the subsequent transations.